# How to invoke sudo password request in Python

Tags: python, linux, user-interface, sudo, pyserial

I've got a USB GPIO electronic gizmo attached to a desktop PC running Linux Mint 17 "Mate"; in this environment the gizmo appears as /dev/ttyACM0. I've written a GUI Python 2.7/Tkinter program to control the gizmo via the pySerial module.  The program works when run from the console using sudo.

Being a GUI program, I want to be able to run it from the "Mate" desktop - but I can't, because being a serial device, accessing the gizmo  requires root privileges obtained via sudo, wot has to be invoked at a Terminal.

```
# here's the offending code
import serial
numa = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 19200, timeout=1)
....
```

How do I invoke the "Enter your password..." routine from ***within*** the Python program so a raw user doesn't have to open a Terminal to enter the password?

Thanks for any advice you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer your question, but instead I'm going to solve your problem.

When you list the device file, you'll see something like this:

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyACM0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Apr  4 11:22 /dev/ttyACM0
```

Both the owner *(root)* and the owner group *(dialout)* have read-write-access (`rw-`), while everybody else isn't able to access the device (`---`). Therefore, instead of giving the program root access to your system, you can simply add the user(s) to the *dialout* group:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG dialout <username>
```

Logging out and back in will be necessary, but afterwards your script will be able to both read and write to the serial interface without the need of a root password.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, Finwood; your solution worked well.  I do wonder about security:  in order to gain simple access to one device (a USB GPIO module) this solution removes the stricture that comes with accessing serial devices in general.

Comment: Yes, this enables general access to serial devices. But is it really a security issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use gksudo rather than sudo

```
from subprocess import call
call('gksudo -D "Program requires root priveledge \nSudo "your command here",shell=True)
```

for example:

```
call('gksudo -D "Override Sudo message " cp /etc/hosts /home/new.hosts',shell=True)
```